# push 5 string from array to new new Array using javascript/ node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, nodes

```js
let dataArray=["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","A10"];

for (const value of dataArray){
 let newArray=[];
 for(i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
  newArray.push(value);
 }
 
 console.log(newArray)
}
```

I am trying to push only 5 string from array but its not working as expectation as my expected output is like this

```
console.log(newArray);

["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5"]
```

I am trying to get first 5 string from dataArray and pushing them in newArray

Comment: You can use [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for this, but if you want to use explicit loops, then you only need 1 loop, not 2. You can remove the outer loop and push `dataArray[i]` (also make sure to change `i=0` to `let i = 0;`, otherwise `i` becomes a global variable)

Comment: Try to understand line wise what your code really does. The output will be clear then, so will the solution

Comment: Why not try: `console.log(dataArray.slice(0, 5));`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
let dataArray=["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","A10"];


 let newArray=[];
 for(i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
  newArray.push(dataArray[i]);
 }
 
 
console.log(newArray);
```

another way is `.slice()`

so you can do just this

```js
let dataArray=["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","A10"];

 console.log(dataArray.slice(0,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

`slice` method will do the job for you.

Eg: `dataArray.slice(0, 5);` - This will return the first 5 items from dataArray.

In your code you are iterating through the dataArray and each item in dataArray is pushed into newArray 5 times and printing it.
Also in each iteration through the dataArray, the variable newArray is reinitialised.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let dataArray=["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","A10"];
let newArr = dataArray.filter((str,index) => {
    if(index < 5){
  return str;
  }
})
console.log(newArr)
```